# How do I specify Git Commit id (hash) when launching a build with TFSBuild.exe?

Tags: git, tfs, tfsbuild

TFSBuild.exe is the method by which you launch TFS build from the command line.   TFSBuild.exe doesn't indicate how to specify a Git commit Id (the hash of the commit).

TFSBuild.exe discusses the /getOption:Custom option which, when used, lets use specify the change-set or label to base the build on, by specifying the change-set or label identifier with the /customGetVersion option.   For a label, you start with an "L".  For a change-set, you start with a "C".

However, there doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to specify a Git commit-id.

Answer (score 2):

You specify the git commit-id using the "Label" syntax, but add a "G:ref:" before the commit ID.  As in: /customGetVersion:LG:ref:

Full syntax:

```
TFSBuild start teamProjectCollectionUrl teamProject definitionName /queue /getOption:Custom /customGetVersion:LG:ref:<hash>
```

Example usage:

```
TFSBuild start http://gitsourceserver:8080/tfs/MyCompany MyTeamProject MyBuildDefinition /queue /getOption:Custom /customGetVersion:LG:ref:0c9cc3ce
```